# socket programming, trouble with try loop

Tags: java, sockets

I've been looking at the Oracle tutorial site to learn basic socket programming. I tried uploading the example on eclipse but when I tried to compile, there is an error with the syntax where the parenthesis are. Why is this happening? Thanks.

```
try (
        Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in))
    ) {
        String userInput;
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
            hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: What Java version are you using? If this is valid syntax, it's only valid in later versions of Java (7 or so, I think)

Comment: I am using version 7. it keeps saying '{' is expected instead of '('

Comment: Any chance you have a Java 7 JRE (runtime environment) but only Java 6 JDK (developer kit)?

Comment: i checked and both are 7

Comment: Where did you look to confirm both settings?

Comment: in the program file in eclipse it says JRE System Library[jre7] and the only jdk i downloaded was version 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Why is this happening?

You are trying to do a "try-with-resources".  That requires Java 7 or later.  Make sure your eclipse project is also set to Java 7, not just your local command line JDK.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: He says in comments he has Java 7

Comment: Yes, but his project might not be configured with it.

Comment: FWIW the code compiles fine in eclipse for me using java 7.

Comment: @user2910237 Check what *source level* you have configured. It can't be 7.

Comment: @EJP could you tell me how i could do that? i'm still new to eclipse.

Comment: @user2910237 No idea in Eclipse, but it will be an attribute of the project somewhere.